# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.asMap

Tags: spring, spring-boot, guava

I am using `spring-boot` for a restfull webservice application.
but while running the application, I am getting below error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.asMap(Lcom/google/common/collect/ListMultimap;)Ljava/util/Map;

**Dependencies:**

```
Spring-boot-starter-parent : 1.5.6.RELEASE
spring-core : 4.3.10.RELEASE
guava : r05
springfox-swagger2 : 2.8.0
```

**pom dependencies:**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>r05</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your dependent lib for `springfox` are not correct.

Please check dependencies for springfox-swagger2 : 2.8.0 [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2/2.8.0).

If you scroll down in above link you can see that `guava` [version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/20.0) need to be 20.0

Try with this change.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>20.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: in project root dir try mvn dependency:tree to see all versions of dependency and see if any of them is getting overridden